# tmux と emacsclient を併用すると、片一方の pane に client がとられてしまう

Tags: emacs, tmux

emacsclient と tmux を併用して、以下の挙動に遭遇しました。

1. `emacs --daemon` を起動
2. `tmux` を起動
3. pane 分割
4. 一方の pane で `emacsclient` を起動 -> 問題なく起動
5. もう一方の pane で `emacsclient` を起動 -> Waiting for Emacs... (そして、 4 の pane で client が２重に起動しているような挙動。２回 client を終了すると shell にもどるので)

になっているのですが、どうしてこのような挙動になるのでしょうか。具体的には、どうして 5 の pane で起動した `emacsclient` が 4 の pane で動くのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emacsclient のソースコードを眺めてみますと、デフォルトでは最初の接続で作成した frame(この場合は terminal frame)を以降の emacsclient による接続でも使用する事が分かります。

**emacs/lib-src/emacsclient.c**

```c
/* Nonzero means don't open a new frame. Inverse of --create-frame.  */
int current_frame = 1;
         :
static void
decode_options (int argc, char **argv)
{
         :
  switch (opt)
    {
         :
      case 't':
        tty = 1;
        current_frame = 0;
        break;
         :

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
         :
  if (current_frame)
    send_to_emacs (emacs_socket, "-current-frame ");
         :
```

**emacs/lisp/server.el**

```lisp
(cl-defun server-process-filter (proc string)
         :
  ;; -current-frame:  Don't create frames.
  (`"-current-frame" (setq use-current-frame t))
```

なお、新たに frame を作成する場合は `-nw/-t/-tty` オプションを指定します。

> **emacsclient(1)**
>
> ```
> -nw, -t, --tty
>
>   open a new Emacs frame on the current terminal
> ```